# Multiplication of each elements in list by specific number

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have written a python program using lists. I want to multiply each element of a list by specific number say y and to print the list.

For example if my inputs are `[1 2 3 4]` and if I multiply the list by 2 then output is like `[2, 4, 6, 8]`. And finally I want to store the result in tuple, not in list. So help me with the code to save list into tuple.

But in the below program I'm getting wrong results that are repeated like `[2, 22, 222, 2222]`
Please help me.

```py
x = list(map(int, input().split(" "))) 
y = input()
a = [i * y for i in x]
print(a)
```

Comment: `a = tuple(i * y for i in x)`

Comment: thany you. it works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `input()` function returns a string and not an int

```
x = list(map(int, input().split(" "))) 
y = int(input())
a  = tuple(i * y for i in x)
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you Hozayfa. Now program behaves exactly as I expected